# RoR Routes: Why does the app assume I want the show action with every URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

So, I'm trying to access other actions in my controller, and it assums I want "show" every time, when I really just want... the action I just had in my URL.

this is in my routes:

```
  map.resources :attachments
```

And when I do

```
domain/attachments/any_action?params
```

I get this error:

```
ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to show. Actions: {list of actions}
```

Using rails 2.3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule in Rails is first route matched, first route served.

Because you define a `resource`, it will consider everything like `domain/attachments/whatever` to be `show` action for the `whatever` stuff.

So two choices here:

- define your other routes and declare them ***before*** the `resource`
- nest your other routes inside the `resource` (I don't know how to do that in Rails 2.x)

Comment: before as in above? or before as in below the resource?

Comment: first match, first served. So first your custom route then resources

Comment: so, above the resource, got it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I know what you are getting at.

Yes show is assumed for singular uses and index for plural.

This is a convention.

Much of the power / magic in rails comes from **"convention over configuration"** and this is one of them.  Yes it could have been /attachment/show/ or /attachments/index but why not just eliminate the show and index if these are the most common and have them available as **defaults** and that is what rails does.

Now, as for actions not being available, lets look at that.  First of all, right off the bat, please do a rake routes at the command line and see what you get.  Also please indicate which actions you are trying.  The restful setup "resources" will make 7 actions available:- index, show, new, create, edit, update and destroy, but not "any action"

Comment: Yes for rails 3.  Rails 2 has a default route at the bottom for any controller/action not otherwise specified but in rails 3 this was removed as a default.  The routes will also give you the _path and _url variables that you should be using for links, forms, etc.